# Rerun ValueConverter on Event

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I am seraching for a way to rerun my `ValueConverter` when a certain event is triggered. The `ValueConverter` calculates the `TimeSpan` to a `Datetime` property and formats it as `x (minutes|hours) ago`. In order to get some sort of refresh on that I need to retrigger the IValueConverter. Can this be done without using hacks like reassigning the same DateTime Value to the property?

This is the Datamodell:

```
        private static DataModell modell = null;
        public  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public  void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info) {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        public DataModell() { }
        public static DataModell Instance {
            get {
                if (modell == null) {

                    modell = new DataModell();
                }

                return modell;
            }
        }
        private    ObservableCollection<HistoryContent> _History = new ObservableCollection<HistoryContent>();
        public ObservableCollection<HistoryContent> History {
            get {

                return _History;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Raise PropertyChanged event

Comment: The DateTime stays the same, only the Timespan calculated within the IValueConverter changes

Comment: Are you wanting to periodically refresh the time?

Comment: Again: Raise PropertyChanged event for the DateTime property

Comment: @crazyGamer that would be best, yes but I would be satisfied with refreshing on certain events

Comment: @SirRufo The DateTime property is within a Object and is stored in a ObservableCollection

Comment: Check out this SO question for how to periodically update UI elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949458/how-to-have-a-wpf-binding-update-every-second. You could set-up a timer that on every `tick` updates the data or calls PropertyChanged.

Comment: @Curunir It does not matter inside which object the property is defined. That object had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the PropertyChanged event of that property. That will cause the Binding to call the ValueConverter and assign the value from ValueConverter to the bound control property.

Comment: I edited the question to show the class the Listbox is bound to. @SirRufo you wanted to say that HistoryContent has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged too?