# Creating audio player on WPF using NAudio. Binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I am creating my audio player on WPF using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).
I am adding a `slider` that will be scroll the song.
XAML:

```
<Slider Height="30" 
                Value="{Binding Path=MediaReader.Position, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Maximum="{Binding Path=MediaReader.Length, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

*Note*. MediaReader - it's a property that returns the object of type `MediaFoundationReader`:

```
MediaFoundationReader mediaReader;
public MediaFoundationReader MediaReader => mediaReader;
```

**Problem**: while the song is plaing the slider property `Value` doesn't change! But by scrolling the thumb of the slider the property `Position` of the `MediaReader` changes.
Why does it work so and how can I solve that?

Comment: The mediareader isn't sending change notifications, so the UI cannot be updated.

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks! Maybe I should create a timer and every tick update the slider?

Comment: you need to wrap the model in a view model that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: @MykhailoPantia, thank you for your answer. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @BorisMakhlin It's one option, however that's going to be heavy on CPU usage. Look on the library's documentation for something that notifies you instead, like an event or callback that updates the position instead.

Comment: How about using a behavior that updates your binding?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44253691/8454410

Comment: @Pawleshhh, thank you! It's a good idea, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look to this tutorial:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-wpf-media-player-using-naudio

The author uses also a slider control and binds the current track position, e.g.:

```
<Slider Grid.Column="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding CurrentTrackLenght, Mode=OneWay}" Value="{Binding CurrentTrackPosition, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="SeekbarControl" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TrackControlMouseDownCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TrackControlMouseUpCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Slider>

public double CurrentTrackPosition
    {
        get { return _currentTrackPosition; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_currentTrackPosition)) return;
            _currentTrackPosition = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTrackPosition));
        }
    }
```

I think you can get the idea behind this...